# Can stdin only be line-buffered?

Tags: c, terminal, stream, stdin

I set `stdin` full-buffered as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    if (setvbuf(stdin, buffer, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ) != 0) { // here
        printf("an error occured.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("number : %d\n", number);
    return 0;   
}
```

**However, the result suggests that `stdin` is still line-buffered.** Why is that?

```
3
number : 3
```

Comment: It's the *terminal program* that controls the "buffering" here. You can possibly change the settings for the terminal, but how to do it depends on your platform (Windows, Linux/macOS/other POSIX, or other OS type).

Comment: How do you know that `stdin` is not fully buffered?

Comment: @JeremyP I entered two characters `3\n`, and `BUFSIZ` is `8192` in my implementation.

Comment: It is not the buffering here but the fact that the terminal puts the data into the `stdin` only on new lines. If you instead pipe the input into your `stdin`, you can see that you can read a character at a time too (before encountering a `\n`)

Comment: @P.P. Sorry but this is not a duplicate of the question you referenced. The questioner here wants to make the input *fully buffered* **not** *unbuffered*. Nominated for reopening.

Comment: @b1sub What are you expecting to happen then? Do you think it should hang in the `scanf`?

Comment: @JeremyP Yes. I assumed that `scanf` won't return unless the buffer is full.

Comment: @b1sub I don't have an answer, but my guess is that `scanf` has access to the internal buffer and simply reads it as soon as there are enough characters in it. You might find that "fully buffered" doesn't mean anything much for input. Why is it that you are hoping to delay any processing until you have a full buffer anyway?

Comment: @JeremyP Just a pure curiosity. =D Thank you for the comments!!